# Debugging a Javascript within Camunda's Script-Task

Tags: javascript, camunda, script-task

I'm trying to merge two arrays in a **Script Task** of type **Javascript** within a **Process** in **Camunda**. Here's my script:

```
var arr1 = execution.getVariableTyped("arr1", true);
var arr2 = execution.getVariableTyped("arr2", true);

var merged = [];

for (var i1 in arr1) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i2 in merged) {
        if (arr1[i1].id == merged[i2].id) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        merged.push(arr1[i1]);
    }
}

for (var i1 in arr2) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i2 in merged) {
        if (arr2[i1].id == merged[i2].id) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        merged.push(arr2[i1]);
    }
}

execution.setVariable("arr1", merged);
execution.removeVariable("arr2");
```

When the mentioned script is executed, it throws an exception:

> Cannot complete task b4fb856a-6a92-11e5-9774-005056c00008: Cannot
>   serialize object in variable 'arr1': SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01009 Unable to
>   map object 'jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray@5ff42b74' to json
>   node

Why is that? What's the problem and how can I fix it? Is there anyway to debug such scripts?

Comment: Debugging depends on your IDE. Apparently, IntelliJ has such a feature: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/debugger-for-jdk8s-nashorn-javascript-in-intellij-idea-13-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashorn has classes like `NativeArray` for Javascript arrays because a Javascript array is not tied to an element type like for example `String[]` in Java. Thus, Nashorn creates an instance of `NativeArray`. Apparently, the process engine is not able to store instances of `NativeArray` since it does not implement `java.io.Serializable` and is not serializable by the JSON and XML serializer either. In fact, the JSON serializer attempts to do so but throws the exception you see.

You can do

```
execution.setVariable("arr1", Java.to(merged, "java.lang.Object[]"));
```

to convert the `NativeArray` to a Java `Object[]`. If you want to access the array from Java code, you could use a more specifically typed array. Source: [Nashorn documentation](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions)

Note:

For **JDK 8 versions >= 1.8u40**, the type handed over is not `NativeArray` but an instance of `ScriptObjectMirror` that wraps a `NativeArray` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392602/reading-nashorn-jo4-and-nativearray) for details). Apparently, the same code can be used to solve the issue.