# Modifying an ArrayList in Javascript results in serialization failure in Camunda

Tags: javascript, java, camunda, script-task

I created a BPMN Collaboration model with a Script-Task of type Javascript in it. Then I instantiated a process instance with a process variable like so:

```
Variable name: arr
Object type name: java.util.ArrayList
Serialization Data Format: application/x-java-serialized-object
Value: [{ "id": 10 }]
```

Then I passed the script task with the following code:

```
var arr = execution.getVariable("arr");
execution.setVariable("arr2", arr);
```

And it ran successfully. Then I amended the script task like this:

```
var arr = execution.getVariable("arr");
arr.add({ "id" : 2 });
execution.setVariable("arr2", arr);
```

And redeployed, re-instantiated; and to my surprise it resulted in an error:

> Cannot submit task form xxx: Cannot serialize object in variable
>   'arr': jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

I just found something new, if I modify the ArrayList like this:

```
var arr = execution.getVariable("arr");
arr.add(2);
execution.setVariable("arr2", arr);
```

It works just fine! And the modified value is:

```
[{ "id": 10 }, 2]
```

Which means `setVariable` has problem serializing the modified list. So how should I serialize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is the same the problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933566/debugging-a-javascript-within-camundas-script-task). Instead of an array created in Javascript, we are dealing with an object here, which apparently Nashorn internally represents as an instance of the class `jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4` and the process engine isn't able to serialize that (with JDK >= 8u40, a `JO4` instance is wrapped in a `ScriptObjectMirror` instance when calling a Java method but the problem is the same).

To create an instance of a Java class, you can use the following code:

```
var HashMap = Java.type("java.util.HashMap");
var instance = new HashMap();
instance.id = 2;
arr.add(instance);
execution.setVariable("arr2", arr);
```

Source: [Nashorn documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html)

Comment: I'm not sure if there exists one or not, but I think a documentation explain these would be really helpful. Thanks.